# Supported languages contains an invalid value

Tags: air, localization, flex4

When I build with Flash Builder 4.6 with Apache Flex 4.9.1 and Air 3.7, I get an error indicating a problem with my "supportedLanguages" node. 
[image]

I have tried all of the following and all have failed:
This way worked in previous versions of the flex sdk:

```
<supportedLanguages>en es de fr ja ko pt ru zh ar pl</supportedLanguages>
```

Second attempt was to add local code:

```
<supportedLanguages>en_US es_ES de_DE fr_FR ja_JP ko_KR pt_BR ru_RU zh_CN ar_SA pl_PL</supportedLanguages>
```

I tried adding commas:

```
<supportedLanguages>en_US,es_ES,de_DE,fr_FR,ja_JP,ko_KR,pt_BR,ru_RU,zh_CN,ar_SA,pl_PL</supportedLanguages>
```

I have local directories for each locale specified in:

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.9.1_3.7\frameworks\locale
E:\dev\myapp\src\locale
```

I also use this line for the compiler:

```
-swf-version=20 -locale=en_US,es_ES,de_DE,fr_FR,ja_JP,ko_KR,pt_BR,ru_RU,zh_CN,ar_SA,pl_PL -allow-source-path-overlap=true -source-path=locale/{locale}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can avoid it, I'll never develop in Flex again. Consider this question no longer valid due to the lack of support from Adobe.